# How to fix missing Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.CloudAdapter.Data for SQL Server PowerShell Module?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssms

When I use the SQL Server PowerShell module, I get an error that an assembly is missing.

I installed SqlServer version 21.0.17240 and SQL Server Management Studio v17.6.

```
Import-Module SqlServer
Get-SqlInstance -MachineName $serverInstance -Credential $credential
```

Error:

```
Get-SqlInstance : Die Datei oder Assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.CloudAdapter.Data, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
In Zeile:2 Zeichen:9  
+         Get-SqlInstance -MachineName $serverInstance -Credential $cre ...  
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-SqlInstance], FileNotFoundException  
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.IaaS.GetSqlInstanceCommand
```

What do I need to do to fulfill the requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE:** I'm reading 21.0.17240 as the version of the `SqlServer` module not your instance of "SQL Server".

`Get-SqlInstance` requires the SQL Server Cloud Adapter be installed. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/get-sqlinstance?view=sqlserver-ps):

> The Get-SqlInstance cmdlet gets a SQL Instance object for each
>   instance of SQL Server that is present on the target computer. If the
>   name of the instance of SQL Server is provided, the cmdlet will only
>   get this specific instance of SQL Server.
>
> You must ensure that you run SQL Server Cloud Adapter on the computer
>   that hosts the instance of SQL Server.

The service was built to support SQL Server hosted on Azure Virtual Machines. Even if your machines are on-prem., you'll need [this service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169301(v=sql.120).aspx) or the commandlet won't work.

My two cents, consider using SMO if you want instance information about a SQL Server instance. Google and you'll find tons of material on using SMO to pull data from SQL Server:

> powershell smo

Now, to your problem, I don't believe Microsoft shipped the SCA for SQL Server 2016 or 2017 either with the engine or in a feature pack, which would mean this commandlet is effectively broken for those releases as stated [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsdesktop/en-US/de0b6b41-34d8-4950-836d-325575b9a514/where-is-the-cloud-adapter-for-sql-server-2016?forum=sqlservermigration). If you're using 2014, you can download the SCA with a feature pack. Maybe you can use the 2014 SCA with a later version of SQL Server, but I don't see that supported anywhere.